# Natural French phrases for 'get out of a vicious circle'?

Tags: expressions, formulation-idiomatique

How do French people usually describe the notion 'get out of a vicious circle' as below?

- I just can't seem to get out of this vicious circle of constantly and consciously  making bad decisions in life. The self-destructive streak in me always draws me to the worse choice of the two.

Comment: "J'ai un mal fou à briser cette spirale infernale (/ spirale autodestructrice) qui me conduit à prendre des mauvaises décisions à tout bout de champ -- et sciemment !"

Comment: Naturellement, je dirais "rompre ce cercle vicieux"

Comment: Ce ne sont pas des commentaires, mais des réponses :-)

Answer (score 4):

Non locuteur natif.

> Je n'arrive tout simplement pas à sortir de ce cercle vicieux qui consiste à prendre constamment et consciemment de mauvaises décisions dans la vie. La tendance autodestructrice en moi m'attire toujours vers le pire choix des deux.

Cercle vicieux existe bien en français.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cercle%20vicieux&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccercle%20vicieux%3B%2Cc0)

http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/cercle-vicieux.php

https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cercle_vicieux

Selon le dernier lien l'on peut utiliser comme synonyme

> enchaînement diabolique

Comment: +1 for "sortir de ce cercle vicieux"

Answer (score 2):

Dans les commentaires, on a deux réponses :

> "J'ai un mal fou à briser cette spirale infernale (/ spirale
> autodestructrice) qui me conduit à prendre des mauvaises décisions à
> tout bout de champ -- et sciemment !" –  Con-gras-tue-les-chiens  Apr
> 19, 2019 at 10:59

> Naturellement, je dirais "rompre ce cercle vicieux" –  Loïc Di
> Benedetto  Apr 19, 2019 at 14:47